# Create an object “car” and have one of its properties display a string

Tags: javascript

1. Define a variable `car`, an Object with the following properties:

   - `model` of `’Nissan’`
   - `color` of `’Blue’`
   - `numWheels`, a number of wheels. Value is `4`
2. The object should also have the following method:

   - Method `drive` that returns `’Vroom!’`

What I tried:

```
const car = {
    model: 'Nissan',
    color: 'Blue',
    numwheels: 4,
    drive: function() {
        return'Vroom!'
    },
}
console.log (car)
```

What I got:

```
{
  model: 'Nissan',
  color: 'Blue',
  numwheels: 4,
  drive: [Function: drive]
}
```

I have changed “console.log (‘Vroom!)”
To “return ‘Vroom!’”
And I get the result I need

Comment: What is the problem you’re encountering? ps: Instead of console logging, just `return 'Vroom!'`. Otherwise your object looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Method `drive` that returns `Vroom!`

In your code, your `drive()` method is logging `Vroom!` to the console, not returning it as the value of the function. Change `console.log('Vroom!')` to `return 'Vroom!'` and use `console.log(car.drive())` instead of `console.log(car)`. Your complete code should look something like this:

```js
const car = {
    model: 'Nissan',
    color: 'Blue',
    numwheels: 4,
    drive: function() {
        return 'Vroom!';
    },
}
console.log (car.drive());
```